# How to set a cookie in headers to allow frontend access to user-data endpoint after login?

Tags: reactjs, flask, axios, google-oauth

I'm using flask with google auth on the backend and react with axios on the frontend

```
import os
import pathlib
import requests
import config
from flask import jsonify, session, abort, redirect, request, Blueprint, url_for
from google.oauth2 import id_token
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import Flow
from pip._vendor import cachecontrol
import google.auth.transport.requests
AUTH_BLUEPRINT = Blueprint("auth", __name__)
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = config.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID
"""this is to set environment to https because OAuth 2.0 only supports https environments"""
os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "1"

"""setting path to the parent directory where the .json file from google is kept"""
client_secrets_file = os.path.join(pathlib.Path(
    __file__).parent, "../client_secret.json")

""" 
    Flow is OAuth 2.0 class that stores 
    all users authorization information
"""
flow = Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
    client_secrets_file=client_secrets_file,
    scopes=[
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
        "openid"
    ],
    # the redirect URI route to after authorization
    redirect_uri="http://127.0.0.1:5000/callback"
)



@AUTH_BLUEPRINT.route("/")
def index():
    """ 
        This is to check if the user is logged in or not
    """
    if "google_id" in session:
        return "logged in"
    else:
        return "logged out"


""""
    Asking the flow class for the authorization (login) url
"""


@AUTH_BLUEPRINT.route("/login")
def login():
    """ Asking the flow class for the authorization (login) url

    Returns:
        _type_: redirect to the authorization url
    """
    # check if the user is already logged in
    if "google_id" in session:
        return redirect(url_for("auth.index"))
    authorization_url, state = flow.authorization_url()
    session["state"] = state
    return redirect(authorization_url)


@AUTH_BLUEPRINT.route("/callback")
def callback():
    """ Callback function to get the authorization code.
    It is called after the user is authenticated

    Returns:
        _type_: _description_
    """
    flow.fetch_token(authorization_response=request.url)

    if session["state"] != request.args["state"]:
        abort(500)

    credentials = flow.credentials
    request_session = requests.session()
    cached_session = cachecontrol.CacheControl(request_session)
    token_request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request(
        session=cached_session)

    id_info = id_token.verify_oauth2_token(
        id_token=credentials._id_token,
        request=token_request,
        audience=config.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID
    )

    ''' defining the results to show on the page'''
    session["google_id"] = id_info.get("sub")
    session["name"] = id_info.get("name")
    '''page to redirect to after authorization'''
    # store the user data in the session which will be return by
    # get_user_data function
    session["user_data"] = id_info
    return redirect("/")
```

The login is working correctly on the backend with the cookie set in browser and I'm able to access the following user-data endpoint

```
def login_is_required(function):
    """ A decorator to check if a user is authorized or not

    Args:
        function (_type_): the function to be decorated
    """
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        """ The wrapper function

        Returns:
            _type_: the function that is decorated
        """
        if "google_id" not in session:
            return abort(401)
        else:
            return function()
    return wrapper


@AUTH_BLUEPRINT.route("/user-data")
@login_is_required
def get_user_data():
    """Return all the user data returned by Google
    ---
    responses:
        200:
            description: Return all the user data returned by Google
            schema:
                type: object
                example:
                            {
                                "at_hash": "gy-uRqy-ckp1xtCVqalMyA",
                                "aud": "5713982095317-p6vv1kttnbjr60u0rs7i8nmkurlft5mj.apps.googleusercontent.com",
                                "azp": "5713982095317-p6vv1kttdgjr60u0rs7i8nmkurlft5mj.apps.googleusercontent.com",
                                "email": "a.kebede@alustudent.com",
                                "email_verified": true,
                                "exp": 1681768052,
                                "family_name": "Kebede",
                                "given_name": "Abebe",
                                "hd": "alustudent.com",
                                "iat": 1681464452,
                                "iss": "https://accounts.google.com",
                                "locale": "en",
                                "name": "Abebe Kebede",
                                "picture": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/AGNmyxayr4UVXSZBNsx8xfeg1NCZxX24vJOASE4AF2gr=s96-c",
                                "sub": "10505877750333961075"
                                }
                            
    """
    return jsonify(session["user_data"])
```

But on the frontend after login-in I'm enable to fetch the data to the user-data endpoint because and there is no cookie set in the header of my frontend while making a request to that endpoint.
here is my login page with react

```
const fetchUser = async () => {
    const currentUser = await axios
      .get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/user-data', { withCredentials: true })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log('Not properly authenticated');
      });
    console.log(currentUser);
    if (currentUser && currentUser.data) {
      navigate('/home');
      console.log('user', currentUser.data);
      dispatch(setIsAuthenticated(true));
      dispatch(setAuthUser(currentUser.data));
    }
  };
  const handleAuth = async () => {
    let timer: NodeJS.Timeout | null = null;
    const googleUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/login';
    const newWindow = window.open(googleUrl, '_blank', 'width=500, height=600');
    if (newWindow) {
      console.log('test1');
      timer = setInterval(() => {
        console.log('test2');
        if (newWindow.closed) {
          console.log("Yay we're authenticated");
          fetchUser();
          if (timer) clearInterval(timer);
        }
      }, 50);
    }
  };


<button
            className="text-white hover:text-black w-full flex items-center justify-center -gap-x-3 py-2.5 border rounded-lg text-sm font-medium hover:bg-gray-50 duration-150 active:bg-gray-100"
            onClick={handleAuth}
          >
            <FcGoogle className="text-2xl mr-4" /> Continue with Google
          </button>
```

I want to fetch the user-data endpoint on the frontend and set the cookie in the header of my frontend after login in for further requests to the backend

Here is my main file

```
  """ The server that runs that servers the API
"""
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS
import config

from routes.auth import AUTH_BLUEPRINT
import os
from flasgger import Swagger


app = Flask(__name__)
swagger = Swagger(app)
# register the blueprints
app.register_blueprint(AUTH_BLUEPRINT, url_prefix="/")


CORS(app, supports_credentials=True)
app.secret_key = config.SECRET_KEY
# app.config['PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME'] = config.PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME

# api status checker
@app.route("/status")
def status():
    """Returns the status of the API"""
    return jsonify({"status": "OK"})

# 404 error handler
@app.errorhandler(404)
def not_found(error):
    """Returns a JSON-formatted 404 status code response"""
    return jsonify({"error": "Not found"}), 404

@app.errorhandler(401)
def unauthorized(error):
    """Returns a JSON-formatted 401 status code response"""
    return jsonify({"error": "Unauthorized"}), 401

@app.errorhandler(500)
def internal_server_error(error):
    """Returns a JSON-formatted 500 status code response"""
    return jsonify({"error": "Internal server error"}), 500



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host=config.HOST, port=config.PORT, debug=True)
```